# Sorting data ($sort) in quer documents dialog of adminMongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Using [adminMongo](https://github.com/mrvautin/adminmongo) as web-ui for MongoDB, I want to filter and order the documents. Filtering works simple:

```
{
    "status": 4
}
```

But additionally, all documents should be sorted by `date` field, which is a unix timestamp. In MySQL I would simply add `ORDER BY date DESC` but as a newbie, It's not clear for me how to do this in adminMongo.

I took a look in the documentation. They execute js code with methods. To get in this, I used the shell and could get my expected data result using the following code:

```
db.getCollection('my-collection').find({"status": 4}).sort({date: -1})
```

However this works on the shell, it creates an error in adminMongo. Seems that adminMongo expects a json document. So we've 2 syntax variants? It's confusing me, since on SQL we've SQL and don't care if we write SQL in any programming language, admin ui or directly on the shell.

I think I've to convert the `find` method to json, but don't know why. According to the docs, we can use `$sort` as `$sort: { 'date': -1}`. Calling `aggreagate()` method on the collection, this works. On adminMongo, I got an error when trying to send something like

```
{
    { "$sort": { 'date': -1} }
}
```

What is the right syntax which I need to use on adminMongo? Where is documented, how I can convert methods like [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) which are used for sorting, to this syntax?

Comment: try `{{"status": 4}, {"date": -1}}`

Comment: @nrgwsth Doesn't work: `Invalid query syntaxSyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 1`

Comment: check the issues section... Sort and aggregate are currently not supported... #114

Comment: I use nosqlclient now. It has also a lack of calling methods after find like `sort()`, but instead it offers a mongo shell. Seems like this is the only way to run all queries as I'm used to from SQL servers.